# How to get the number of threads per cores in python

Tags: python, multithreading

My computers CPU has 4 cores and 2 threads for each core, as I can get it by `lscpu` command:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
...
```

I can get the numbers of cores by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` python standard. But i can't find any way to get the number of threads per core by python. I know i can execute `lscpu` command and get the number of threads by parsing the output in python. But Is there any standard solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module in python3.

```
python3 -m pip install psutil
```

The `psutil.cpu_count` method returns the number of logical CPUs in the system (same as os.cpu_count in Python 3.4) or None if undetermined. logical cores means the number of physical cores multiplied by the number of threads that can run on each core (this is known as Hyper Threading). If logical is False return the number of physical cores only (Hyper Thread CPUs are excluded) or None if undetermined.

```
import psutil

threads_count = psutil.cpu_count() / psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, But both of commands return 4 for me! Expected is 2.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu. @AmirFo What system/OS are you running?

Comment: I am on ubuntu too!

Answer (score 4):

[edit]: If you only need the tread count per core, you can do like this (`OSX` and `linux`):

```
import psutil
print(f'thread count per core: {psutil.cpu_count() // psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)}')
```

You will have to try if this works on `windows`, I have no way to tell.

---

On `linux` you can do like this to run your command from python, with the `subprocess` module from the standard library:

```
p = subprocess.run(['lscpu'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(f'lscpu: {p.stdout}')
```

This command does not exist on `OSX`, and IDK for `windows`.

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question, I can do this by myself, The question is how to get it by python standard!

Comment: This is python code, and `subprocess` is from the std lib - what exactly do you mean by "python standard"? What system (OS) are you working with?

Comment: The way you get the number is by executing `lscpu` and will not work in Windows or OSX, Python standard means the library that provides these information 
 like `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` and can be executed everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the precisions; I edited my answer to address these new requirements.